# How to get the starting bit number when using bit fields (C++)

Tags: c++

Assume we have a struct like this

```
struct my_struct
{
    uint16_t a : 2;
    uint16_t b : 6;
    uint16_t c : 8;
}my_struct

my_struct temp;
```

Is there anyway to get the starting/ending bit of `temp.b`? in other words, is there a syntax/built-in function in C++ that does the following:

```
first_function(temp.b) // returns 2, since b starts on the second bit of the struct in the computers memory
second_function(temp.b) // Returns 8, since the last bit of b is the 8th bit of the struct in the computers memory
```

Hope my question is clear

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the *actual* problem you need to solve, and why do you think knowing the "bits" will solve that problem?

Comment: This question is clear and doesn't need to be closed. The answer is, of course, *no*, but it doesn't make the question unclear.

Comment: You could do `memset(&temp, 0xFF, sizeof temp);` and then `temp.b = 0;` and then look at the bits to find the 0 bits.  That may be a useful start for writing your own first_function and second_function routines.

Comment: By the way, it's implementation defined how bits in the integer are packed (or not) and in which order they are present in the integer. That means `b` in one compiler could be bits `2` to `7`, while in another it could be bits `10` to `15`.

Comment: @Eljay just hacked together a solution that uses your basic idea, and it works: https://godbolt.org/z/1W1ro3h3o (It uses `__builtin_popcount` and statement expressions for convenience but you get the idea). A `second_function` equivalent would probably involve iterating the bytes in reverse. Nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your question is clear, but sadly no - such function does not exist. Perhaps, there is a way to achieve what you want to do using some other means.

Answer (score 0):

No, such functions don't exist in standard library. Furthermore, the language doesn't guarantee that your assumptions about the order of the bit fields match with the language implementation.